# How do you use Android's default font (Roboto) families?

Tags: android, fonts

I have a TextView that I want to style. I know that **sans-serif** font family
uses the font Roboto.

```
<TextView
    android:fontFamily="serif"/>
```

I only get the following suggestions for `fontFamily`:

- serif
- serif-monospace
- sans-serif
- sans-serif-condensed
- sans-serif-smallcaps

How do you use the rest of the aliases declared in **/system/etc/font.xml**?

```
<familyset version="22">
    ...
    <!-- Note that aliases must come after the fonts they reference. -->
    <alias name="sans-serif-thin" to="sans-serif" weight="100" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-light" to="sans-serif" weight="300" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-medium" to="sans-serif" weight="500" />
    <alias name="sans-serif-black" to="sans-serif" weight="900" />
    <alias name="arial" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="helvetica" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="tahoma" to="sans-serif" />
    <alias name="verdana" to="sans-serif" />
    ...
</familyset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, `alias` tags are not being "scanned" by Android Studio so they appear in suggestions dropdown.
Doing like so is okay:

```
<TextView
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"/>
```

Cheers!